# Nested elements with JAXB where element holds attribute and element value at the same time

Tags: java, jaxb, marshalling, moxy

Environment: JAXB 2.1.2 with EclipseLink MOXy

Requirement:

I would like to get such an XML when marshalled:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root id="id123">
   <email>test@gmail.com</email>
   <address type="short">...</address>
</root>
```

I model this with these two classes:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name="root")
public class ClassA {

    @XmlAttribute(name="id")
    private String id = null;

    @XmlElement(name="address")
    private Address addr = new Address();

    // and some getters setters
}
```

and

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Address {

    @XmlElement(name="address")
    private String address = null;

    @XmlAttribute(name="type")
    private String type = null;

}
```

What I get is this, where address gets nested twice:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root id="id123">
   <email>test@gmail.com</email>
   <address type="short">
      <address>...</address>
   </address>
</root>
```

How can I remove one hierarchy?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do the following leveraging `@XmlValue`:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Address {

    @XmlValue
    private String address = null;

    @XmlAttribute(name="type")
    private String type = null;

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/jaxb-and-complex-types-with-simple.html

Comment: does your web-site work fine ? I can`t open any links from it

Comment: @AnNik - I just tried it and it worked?  Which link did you try?

Comment: @AnNik - I just tried the link you posted from my phone and it came up fine.

Comment: @Doughan - please, can you look at that post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29686607/jaxb-many-duplicate-elements-and-inherited-tree

Comment: hm, strange LJ opns fine for me, only your web site has problems.